# How to clear a few tables content in same time

Tags: c#, mysql

I wrote this code to delete a table from my database at Mysql and its working fine.
How can I delete a few tables at the same time with minumum code?
Thanks

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=abcd";
    using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE myproject.words", cnn))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just chain the commands

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = 
       new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE myproject.words; TRUNCATE TABLE myproject.other;"  
       , cnn))
```

Comment: Great. Thank so much.

Comment: If you use that as the answer then you can click the check